# Can't add objects in array Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have Java service which retrieves table from oracle database and I want to display the result in Angular application, also I have an array of Objects in Angular:

`resultSet:Info[]=[];`

service:

```
 pastHourInfo() {
        const url='/SearchApp-1.0/users/transaction';
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((data:any)=>data));
    }
```

this is my service subscribtion:

```
checkPasHourInfo() {
        this.searchService.pastHourInfo().subscribe(data => {
            console.log("we got: ",data);
            this.resultSet.push(data);
            console.log(this.resultSet.length);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error",error);

    },);
```

Problem is the next. The result is 77 rows . 
`console.log("we got: ",data)` gives correct result. [you cans see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSpTK.png)

but `console.log(this.resultSet.length);` prints "1" when it must be 77.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to push array into an array?

Comment: You are pushing array inside array. Just replace it like this :`this.resultSet = data;` instead of `this.resultSet.push(data);`

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing an array into an array. So your array looks like this

```
resultSet[].length = 1;
resultSet[0].length = 77;
```

Instead of doing:

```
this.resultSet.push(data);
```

try this:

```
this.resultSet.concat(data);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot it seems that your are pushing the `array` into your result `array`, you could spread your data into the array as such:

```
this.resultSet.push(...data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add array into another array as below:

```
this.resultSet.concat(data)
```